# using a XR1071 as a LPF/HPF/VCA

Tags: audio, synthesizer

In my continued quest to design a poly synth I have decided to use XR1071(http://www.cq-dx.ru/upload/pdf/X/XR-1071.PDF) but only the right audio channel. would this configuration work for my purpose (a LPF/HPF/VCA)?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work as a: -

1. LPF - bass booster (but not bass cutter)
2. HPF - treble booster (but not treble cutter)
3. Voltage controlled amplifier

What it wouldn't do (and this is as important for a good synth as nearly anything) is band pass filter - synths use these a lot - in fact I would say it's fundamental to synths - without being able to sweep thru a range of the spectrum with a BPF (peaking filter), it's like having a car without wheels.

Comment: so how would I connect an adsr to this?

Comment: also if I were to use the PBP-10.7 bpf, would I put it before or after the xr1071?